# release build crashes with expo-router

Tags: android, react-native, expo, expo-router

I have fresh expo project created by: `npx create-expo-app`

I've followed https://docs.expo.dev/routing/installation/#quick-start to setup **expo-router**. according to the docs I did only 3 step:

1. add `"scheme": "app-name"` to the `app.json`
2. add `"expo-router/babel"` to the `babel.config.js`
3. add `"main": "expo-router/entry"` to `package.json`

and then run:

```
npx expo run:android --variant release
```

app crashes on startup with no error message!

expo-sdk: 49

here is my logcat logs https://uploadb.me/pr7ouyuhv8mi/log.txt.html